# Phonegap/Cordova how to remove floating action button on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am running Phonegap on Android 5.1.1 device and it has this Floating Action button sitting in the corner. How would i remove it??

I have not seen other threads about this for Cordova. Would i remove it from the config.xml??

Answer (score 0):

Set the android target SDK to version 22

```
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
```

Comment: yes, targetSdkVersion is the version used to compile the app, minSdkVersion is the lower version supported, right now it's 14 (android 4.0) for the latest corodova version